# jQuery $.get request not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, get

I have a file upload form, the following javascript fires as soon as the form is submitted:

```
$("#uploader").submit(function() {
    $("#indicator").show();
    alert("Submitted");
    var refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $.get("progress.php?getprogress&randval=" + Math.random(), function(data) {
            alert("Got " + data);
            $("#indicator .bar div").width(data + "%");
            if (data == 100) {
                clearTimeout(refresh);
                $("#indicator").addClass("done");
            }
        });
    }, 250);
});
```

I added some alerts to debug, I get the `alert("Submitted")`, but not the one alerting the data. The php is fine, opening it in a separate window gives the correct values, but the javascript does not get it. Another weird thing is that if I stop the page load, the `alert()` with the value fires and code is processed.

Comment: Debug with `console.log()`, not with `alert()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved this by using an `<iframe>`:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" target="theiframe">...</form>
<iframe name="theiframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Still using javascript, but no `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

You are not cancelling the form submission, that means your page will refresh. To cancel the submission you can call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("#uploader").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

---

Just moving comments into the answer since your question actually has more to it than what you wrote above.

It is impossible to do two actions on the submit and expect them both to happen. Especially when one is trying to run code as the age is submitting. There are JavaScript libraries that do file uploads, you might want to look into them. BUT the basic idea is submitting the form to a hidden iframe on the page.

```
<form action="YourSubmitPage.php" method="POST" target="hiddenIframe">
    ...fileds here...
</form>
<iframe id="hiddenIframe" name="hiddenIframe" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: The problem is that the file upload is not AJAXified, so I can't `e.preventDefault();`. Is there a method to somehow let the form run, but also use AJAX?

Comment: You can not run both! You can submit the form to a hidden iframe, than you would not need to cancel the form submission.

Comment: So I will have to rely on a plugin or something like that (iFrames)?

Comment: Ok, using an `<iframe>` works, although I expected a neater solution, anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: A neater solution? You can not possibly submit the same page and run code at the same time. Submitting the page is the same thing as clearing a whiteboard. You start from scratch. The hidden iframe is a clean solution and there are plugins that do that along with using the XHR object for browsers that support file upload that way.

Answer (score -1):

I hope your function is inside a `$(document).ready()` statement